# An expression for 2-dimensional element as a sum of differences of elements?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

For 1-dimension, it's simple.

$a_{n}=a_{1}+\sum_{i=2}^{n}(a_{i}-a_{i-1})$

But what would be the corresponding identity for 2-dimension?

In other words, if we put

$a_{n,m}=a_{1,1}+X$

then how can we express $X$ as an elegant sum of differences of $a_{ij}$ s?

The first thing that comes into mind is of course from (1,1) to (n,m), but I failed to put this into an elegant summation of differences of $a_{ij}$ s.

Comment: Take any path from $(1, 1)$ to $(n, m)$ and consider the same sum as in $1$ dimension. But more interesting would be to ask for some discrete analogue of Stokes' theorem (the first identity is a discrete analogue of the fundamental theorem of calculus).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan "Take any path from (1,1) to (n,m) and consider the same sum" This was what I tried at first, I edited the post. But your suggestion to think about Stokes theorem seems interesting although I still couldn't put that into equation.